# using tts from microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk in js

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I don't find the way to use the text-to-speech(tts) using microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk. I only find how to use speech-to-text.

```
import * as SpeechSDK from 'microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk';
```

now

```
SpeechSDK. //nothing like tts here
```

Answer (score 0):

This sdk only provides functions for Speech-to-Text and Speech Translation. TTS sdk only available for C++ and C# .
Pls refer to [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-text-to-speech) to call rest API to use TTS. And you can find demos [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-TTS) .